# MySQL partitioning for table with huge inserts and deletes

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-partitioning

I am having a table in which we have some 20 million entries inserted(blind insertion without any constraints) per day. We have two foreign keys and one of it is a reference id to a table with some 10 million entries.

I am planning to delete all the data in this table older than a month, because this data is not needed anymore. But the problem is that with the huge number of insertions happening, if i start deleting, the table will be locked and insertions will be blocked.

I wanted to know if we can use partitioning on the table based on month. This way, i was hoping that when i try deleting all the data older than 2 months, this data should be in a different partition and insertions should be happening in a different partition, and the delete lock will not be blocking the read lock.

Please tell me if this is possible. I am fairly new to using DB, so please let me know if there is something wrong with my thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html)

> For **InnoDB** and BDB tables, MySQL uses table locking only if you
>   explicitly lock the table with LOCK TABLES. For these storage engines,
>   avoid using LOCK TABLES at all, because InnoDB uses automatic
>   row-level locking and BDB uses page-level locking to ensure
>   transaction isolation.

I'm not sure you even have an issue. Have you tested this and seen locking issues, or are you just theorizing about them right now?

Comment: I did not verify it practically, I was thinking this might be a concern and wanted to confirm it before proceeding. I will verify it and see once.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has partitioning as of version 5.1.

You can run this query to verify if your version of MySQL supports partitioning:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_partitioning';
```

Then you can read the manual to learn how to use it:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I also wanted to know if the locking will be on table level or on partition level when deleting. I want to delete all the data in one partition while inserting in other partition, and i want to do it without insertions being blocked. Is it possible?